# Php обходит условие

Tags: php

Ничего понять не могу. Делаю поиск. Вот коды

html

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search_box" class='search_box'/>
 <select name="where" class="input-xlarge">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Везде</option>
  <option value="4">Скрипты</option>
  <option value="5">Программы</option>
  <option value="6">Для телефона</option>
  <option value="7">Видео</option>
  <option value="8">Аудио</option>
<option value="9">Книги</option>
<option value="10">Ключи</option>
<option value="11">Дизайн</option>
<option value="12">Остальное</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Поиск" class="search_button" />
</form>
```

php

```
  $s_word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
$s_word = strip_tags($word);
$s_where = $_POST['where'];

if ($s_where == 0) {
$sql = "SELECT id_m, title, id_category FROM table1 WHERE text_full LIKE '%" . $s_word . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $word . "%' ORDER BY title LIMIT 50";
} else {
$sql = "SELECT id_m, title, id_category FROM table1 WHERE id_category = '$s_where' AND text_full LIKE '%" . $s_word . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $word . "%' ORDER BY title LIMIT 50";
}
```

Если селект не выбран, то отправляется 0 и поиск идёт везде, а если выбран, то поиск идёт в выбранной категории (id). На деле ищет везде, как ни крути, что не выбирай. Уже голову сломал.

Comment: В `$_POST['where']` что в этот момент валяется? Как вы определили, что ищет везде?

    WHERE id_category = '$s_where' AND text_full LIKE '%" . $s_word . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $word . "%'

==

    где ЛИБО (id_category = $s_where И text_full LIKE %$s_word%), ЛИБО title LIKE %$word%

Comment: <select name="where" ...

Comment: не работает, стёр второй sql (оставил пустым), всё равно выполняется первый запрос

Comment: Я могу долго повторять

> В `$_POST['where']` что в этот момент валяется?

Comment: передаётся value выбранного элемента из списка, выбираешь скрипты, пост ловит 4 например

Comment: Пост неверно передаётся, прописал 4 вместо переменной, всё заработало

Comment: @Rammsteinik

> Я могу долго повторять

что  
находится  
в конкретной  
переменной  
после  
получения  
запроса